# Spring MVC new row in database is created while want to update

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I write my first form using Spring MVC pattern and Hibernate.

I have a problem when I want to update existing row in table.
After click "Edit" Buttno in a table, correct row is found in db. Then I can update "name" field and click SAVE button. Than in database i created new row with new ID.

I have wrote two `System.out` to check current values of object.

**My Controller class:**

```
@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/")
public class InterventionController {

@Autowired
private InterventionService interventionService;

@GetMapping("/")
public String viewHomePage(Model model){
    List<InterventionModel> interventionList = interventionService.listAll();
    model.addAttribute("interventionList", interventionList);
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/new")
public String addInterventionForm(Model model){
    InterventionModel interventionModel = new InterventionModel();
    model.addAttribute("interventionModel", interventionModel);
    System.out.println(model.toString());
    return "new_intervention";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveIntervention(@ModelAttribute("interventionModel")InterventionModel interventionModel){
    System.out.println("Object retreived from editing view "+interventionModel); // <- just to check in console object attributes
    interventionService.save(interventionModel);
    return "redirect:/";
}

@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
public ModelAndView showEditInterventionForm(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("edit_intervention");
    InterventionModel interventionModel = interventionService.get(id).get(); // <-- Optional received from service layer
    mav.addObject("interventionModel", interventionModel);
    System.out.println("Object retrieved from database : "+interventionModel); // <- just to check in console object attributes
    return mav;
}

@GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
public String deleteIntervention(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
    interventionService.delete(id);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

My `InterventionModel` class doesn't contain any annotation. I don't know if that is a mistake, but that object is DTO between controller and service layer. In the service layer, it is mapped to the entity which is annotated `@Entity`.

```
public class InterventionModel {

private Long id;
private String name;

public InterventionModel() {
}

public InterventionModel(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "InterventionModel{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
} }
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Interventions</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
    <h1>Interventions</h1>
    <a href="new">Create new Intervention</a>
    <br><br>
    <table border="2" cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Intervention Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="intervention :${interventionList}">
            <td th:text="${intervention.id}">Intervention Id</td>
            <td th:text="${intervention.name}">Name</td>
            <td>
                <a th:href="@{'/edit/' + ${intervention.id}}">Edit</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a th:href="@{'/delete/' + ${intervention.id}}">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and **edit_intervention.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Edit Intervention</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Edit Intervention</h1>
    <br/>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${interventionModel}" method="post">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Intervention ID</td>
<!--                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{id}" readonly="readonly"/></td>-->
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{id}" readonly="readonly"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Intervention name</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is curious for me. Object when is retrieved from DB has proper attributes (id, name) than Model is created and sent to `edit_intervention.html` form. After changing name, it goes back to save method but there ID number is "null", instead of name which contains changed new value.

 For me (as a beginner) it looks like no all attributes are transferred from the view to the save method in controller. When we have ID set to "null" it's a sign for hibernate to create new row.

 I guess there is a minor failure which I cannot find.

 Logs from terminal when I call update form:
[image] 

 and view how table after modification looks like:
[image]

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

As you see your id field is null. Because probably the Long value wasn't set. 
In entity class you should mark id property as `@Id`, also you can always add the `@GeneratedValue` annotation above.

Comment: '@Entity' class is set as you said. 
When I get 'id' from database it comes to controller with proper 'id' and 'name' values. Than it goes to 'edit_intervention.html' view where we can edit 'name' value and save again. And there is a magic which I don't understand. Object which we receive from view layer contains changed 'name' field but 'null' 'id' number. It looks like 'id' lost somewhere between controller and view layers

Comment: @EnGoPy, alright, I see. It could be an issue that u don't have setter for id. Try to add it.

`public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id= id;
}`

Comment: Your tip about setter was 50% right :)
What was a reason? In the mapping class, there was no constructor which created entity with both values -> id and name. Because the wrong written Mapper class, edited entity went to the service layer ONLY with name set. That way hibernate had "null" value for id and every time it created duplicate instead of updating already existing.
 Best regards.

Comment: Great. Feel free to use [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). It will solve all boilerplate for entities.